# S3: Access Denied even with AmazonS3FullAccess attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When invoking this lambda function:

```
    var params = {
        Bucket: sourceBucket,
        Key: sourceKey,
        ACL: 'public-read-write'
    };

    s3.putObjectAcl(params, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            callback(err)
        }
    })
```

I tried 2 execution roles for this lambda function, but still encountered the above error:

1. IAM Role with AmazonS3FullAccess policy attached.
2. IAM Role with the following policies:

   - AWSLambdaExecute policy
   - This Inline policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

May I know what am I doing wrong or have missed? Thank you!

Comment: What account/bucket [Block Public Access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-control-block-public-access.html) settings do you have? What S3 bucket policy do you have?

Comment: @jarmod Block all Public Access for this bucket only, and an empty bucket policy.

Comment: If you’ve blocked public access then you won’t be able to make an object public and your request will be denied. That’s the whole point of the BPA settings.

Comment: Thank you Jarmod, I've finally made sense of it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was answered by jarmod in the comments:

Disable the "Block Public Access" Setting in your bucket.

Why?

"If an object is written to an AWS Account or S3 bucket with S3 Block Public Access enabled, and that object specifies any type of public permissions via ACL or policy, those public permissions are blocked. "

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/block-public-access